# PowerShell regex filter files

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to filter files using PowerShell, and I need to insert a new line character in between `</tr><tr>` to break those into separate lines and then remove all the lines that match `<tr>` lots of characters `BTE` lots of characters `</tr>` and save the files in place.

Forgive me, as I am new to PowerShell, and this is simple in SED, but I must use PowerShell. This is what I have but could be completely wrong.

```
Get-Content *.htm | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '</tr><tr>', '</tr>\r\n<tr>'; $_}f
Get-Content *.htm | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '<tr>.*BTE.*</tr>', ''; $_}
```

Comment: Is the replace working? You'd need to pipe to a `Set-Content` to write the changes back to the file at the end.

Comment: When I use the below, it says file in use.
Get-Content *.htm | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '</tr><tr>', '</tr>\r\n<tr>'; $_} | Set-Content *.htm

Comment: I am going to assume the F at the end of the first line is typo? If arco is right about what you need to be doing we can chain these changes instead of reading the file twice.

Comment: You cant read and write the same file in a pipe.

Comment: The f was a typo, but I rebooted my computer to ensure nothing else could be locking the file and when I run the syntax below, I get the file in use error.  
`Get-Content *.htm | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '</tr><tr>', '</tr>\r\n<tr>'; $_} | Set-Content *.htm`

Comment: What is *"SED"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it just sounds like you need to save your changes back to the original files. Also we should just be able to make these changes in one pass instead of reading the files twice.

```
Get-ChildItem *.htm | Foreach-Object {
    $singleFileName = $_.FullName
    (Get-Content $singleFileName) -replace '</tr><tr>', "</tr>`r`n<tr>" -replace '<tr>.*BTE.*</tr>' | Set-Content $singleFileName
}
```

You can't read and write to the same file in the pipe. We place `(Get-Content $singleFileName)` in parenthesis so that the whole file is read at once.

```
Get-Content $singleFileName | Set-Content $singleFileName
```

As each line is passed down the pipe the file is left open so that `Set-Content` can't write to it.

Comment: This worked, but apparently the replace isn't correct, I need the replace to first insert a line break to separate the lines and then remove the whole line.  Any clues on inserting that line break between </tr><tr>? I thought I could use \r\n

Comment: I updated the post to remove a code anomaly that I left. I also used PowerShell newline. Check my update.

Comment: The updated code inserts `r`n between, but not the line break.

Comment: @josgan Ops... It's inside single quotes so it is being taken literally.. My bad. Updated

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to insert the line break if RegEx is able to capture the group like this.

```
Get-ChildItem *.htm  | Foreach-Object {
    $singleFileName = $_.FullName
    ([RegEx]::Matches((Get-Content  $singleFileName),'<tr>.*?</tr>')).Value|?{$_ -notlike '<tr>*BTE*</tr>'} | Set-Content $singleFileName
}
```